# Xpages: Open Modal from within Modal Dialogs

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I want to replicate the same functionality as Modal dialog. Once a modal dialog is opened, it curtains (locks) the parent window. Now, If I have some button which opens a document in another Modal window, it does not curtain parent modal window (original window is still curtained).[image]

Comment: You should tell us which framework you are using - looks like Bootstrap. If so, then learn how to create a modal from the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: I am using bootstrap (via theme). And these modals are created using xe:dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Oliver Busse points out in the comments, this is not officially supported by Bootstrap 3. From [their documentation on modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals):

[image: multiple open modals not supported]

If you're still intent on achieving this, any solution you create will rely custom code (and not in the Bootstrap theme you're currently using). As a proof of concept, I suggest you read up on [this article](http://miles-by-motorcycle.com/fv-b-8-670/stacking-bootstrap-dialogs-using-event-callbacks), which achieves what I believe you're looking for. The main functionality seems to lie in triggering additional CSS classes to emulate the backdrop effect, whenever a subsequent modal button is clicked.

Here's the source for [the demo](http://miles-by-motorcycle.com/static/bootstrap-modal/index.html) from the linked article. Here is the excerpted JavaScript, which applies the class of `fv-modal-stack` to the underlying modals, and increments the z-index accordingly.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#openBtn').click(function () {
        $('#myModal').modal({
            show: true
        })
    });

    $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
        $(this).removeClass('fv-modal-stack');
        $('body').data('fv_open_modals', $('body').data('fv_open_modals') - 1);
    });

    $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
        // keep track of the number of open modals
        if (typeof ($('body').data('fv_open_modals')) == 'undefined') {
            $('body').data('fv_open_modals', 0);
        }

        // if the z-index of this modal has been set, ignore.
        if ($(this).hasClass('fv-modal-stack')) {
            return;
        }
        $(this).addClass('fv-modal-stack');
        $('body').data('fv_open_modals', $('body').data('fv_open_modals') + 1);
        $(this).css('z-index', 1040 + (10 * $('body').data('fv_open_modals')));
        $('.modal-backdrop').not('.fv-modal-stack')
            .css('z-index', 1039 + (10 * $('body').data('fv_open_modals')));
        $('.modal-backdrop').not('fv-modal-stack')
            .addClass('fv-modal-stack');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another [article](http://xpagesandmore.blogspot.nl/2015/05/bootstrap-js-modal-plugin-in-xpages_25.html) from Johnny Oldenburger.

I don't know this is the right one. But show it.